# Proof of Corollary in localizing $\operatorname{Tor}_*$ in Weibel

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

In Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*, one has the following lemma (p 72):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.

> Lemma 3.2.11 If $\mu : A \rightarrow A$ is multiplication by a central element $r \in R$, so are the induced maps $\mu_* : \operatorname{Tor}^R_n(A,B) \rightarrow \operatorname{Tor}^R_n(A,B)$ for all $n$ and $B$.

I would like to prove the following corollary:

> Corollary 3.2.12 If $A$ is an $R/r$-module, then for every $R$-module $B$ the $R$-modules $\operatorname{Tor}_*^R(A,B)$ are actually $R/r$-modules, that is, annihilated by the ideal $rR$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

We want to show that $rR$ also annihilates the $R$-modules $\operatorname{Tor}_*^R(A,B)$.

Since $\forall r' \in rR$, $r' = rc$ for some $c \in R$, it suffices to show that the induced maps $\mu_* : \operatorname{Tor}^R_n(A,B) \rightarrow \operatorname{Tor}^R_n(A,B)$ are the zero map for all $n$ and $B$, where $\mu : A \rightarrow A, a \mapsto ra$. Since multiplication by $r$ is an $R$-module chain map $\tilde{\mu} : P \rightarrow P$ where $P \rightarrow A$ is a projective resolution

$$\begin{matrix}
...\to&P_1&\xrightarrow{d_1} &P_0&\xrightarrow{d_0}&A&\rightarrow &0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\tilde{\mu}_1}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\tilde{\mu}_0}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\mu}\\
...\to &P_1&\xrightarrow{d_1} &P_0&\xrightarrow{d_0} &A&\rightarrow &0
\end{matrix} $$

As $\_ \otimes_R B$ is right exact, we have

$$\begin{matrix}
...\to&P_1 \otimes B&\xrightarrow{d_1 \otimes B} &P_0\otimes B&\xrightarrow{d_0 \otimes B}&A\otimes B&\rightarrow &0\\
&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\tilde{\mu}_1\otimes B}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\tilde{\mu}_0\otimes B}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\mu\otimes B}\\
...\to &P_1\otimes B&\xrightarrow{d_1 \otimes B} &P_0\otimes B&\xrightarrow{d_0 \otimes B} &A\otimes B&\rightarrow &0
\end{matrix} $$

By assumption, $rR$ annihilates $A$, hence $\mu\otimes B : A\otimes B \to A\otimes B, a\otimes b \mapsto ra\otimes b = 0$ is the zero map. Since the
following diagram commutes

$$\begin{matrix}
P_0\otimes B&\xrightarrow{d_0 \otimes B}&A\otimes B\\
\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\tilde{\mu}_0\otimes B}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\mu\otimes B}\\
P_0\otimes B&\xrightarrow{d_0 \otimes B} &A\otimes B
\end{matrix} $$

i.e. $(\mu\otimes B) \circ (d_0\otimes B )= (d_0\otimes B )\circ (\tilde{\mu}_0\otimes B)$ and $(d_0\otimes B )$ may not identically be the $0$ map, then this implies that $\tilde{\mu}_0\otimes B$ has to be the $0$ map. By induction, we can prove that $\tilde{\mu}_n\otimes B$ are $0$ maps for all $n$. Hence the induced map $\mu_*$ on the subquotient $Tor^R_n(A,B)$ of $P_n \otimes B$ is obviously the zero map for all $n$. Therefore, $Tor^R_n(A,B)$ is annihilated by $rR$. $\square$

Does the proof seem ok? Is there something missing in the proof? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't read your whole proof, but is there a reason you don't want to use the lemma you quoted ? Because it's a one-line proof if you use it: multiplication by $r$ in $Tor_n^R(A,B)$ is induced by multiplication by $r$ on $A$ (this is the lemma), but by hypothesis this is the zero map on $A$, so it induces the zero map on $Tor_n^R(A,B)$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Cool, I was trying to make the 'induced map' precise, for instance, this is a question, what guarantees that the induced map of a zero map is zero? In general, when it says induced, does this mean the same map on the quotient or a restriction of the same map OR a combination of $\mu$ and another map can also mean induced, that is what I was not sure about, so I tried to 'show' the induced map and prove it once more unfortunately, similar to the proof in the lemma.

Comment: I think you can only prove that $Im(\tilde{\mu}_n\otimes B) \subseteq ker(d_0 \otimes B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute $\mathrm{Tor}(A,B)$ starting from a projective resolution of $B$
$$ \cdots \to Q_2 \to Q_1 \to Q_0 \to B \to 0. $$
Tensoring with $A$ yields the complex
$$ \cdots \to A\otimes_R Q_2 \to A\otimes_R Q_1 \to A\otimes_R Q_0 \to 0 $$
whose homology groups are $\mathrm{Tor}^R_n(A,B)$. It is now clear that if $r\in R$ acts as zero on $A$, then $r$ acts as zero on each $A\otimes_RQ_n$, and so acts as zero on each $\mathrm{Tor}_n^R(A,B)$.

In fact, all this works in the noncommutative setting, so if $B$ is a left $R$-module and $A$ is an $S$-$R$-bimodule, then each $A\otimes_RQ_n$ is a left $S$-module, and so each $\mathrm{Tor}^R_n(A,B)$ is a left $S$-module.

Comment: All that‘s true in general is that the sequence $$A\otimes Q_1\to A\otimes Q_0\to A\otimes B\to 0$$ is exact. The tor functors measure the non-exactness.

Comment: Why does the exact sequence you gave stop at $A \otimes Q_1$?  What is the proof for it? Why for instance the sequence I gave is not exact? I know intuitively it can't be so because why then calculate $Tor_n$ etc. but what is the argument for it. I do like the proof you gave for the Cor.

Comment: The functor $A\otimes_R-$ is always right exact, so sends the exact sequence $Q_1\to Q_0\to B\to 0$ to the exact sequence $A\otimes Q_1\to A\otimes Q_0\to A\otimes B\to 0$.

Comment: Right, but in this case, when you take a projective resolution of B, then the chain complex is exact, so isn't $Q_2 \to Q_1 \to Q_0 \to B \to 0$ not exact? And by the same argument, make $A\otimes_R Q_2 \to A\otimes_R Q_1 \to A\otimes_R Q_0 \to 0 $ exact (by right exactness of the functor)? That is what I am a bit confused about.

Comment: Sorry, repeating my question but is $Q_2 \to Q_1 \to Q_0 \to B \to 0$ not exact from my explanation above and if not, why not so?

Comment: A functor $T$ is right exact if it sends an exact sequence $L\to M\to N\to 0$ to an exact sequence $T(L)\to T(M)\to T(N)\to 0$. Next, if we have an injective cogenerator $E$ we know that this latter sequence is exact if and only if the sequence $0\to\Hom(T(N),E)\to\mathrm{Hom}(T(M),E)\to\Hom(T(L),E)$ is exact. Doing this for $T=-\otimes X$ (or for any functor admitting a right adjoint) and using the tensor-hom adjunction, this equals the sequence $0\to\Hom(N,\Hom(X,E))\to\Hom(M,\Hom(M,\Hom(X,E))\to\Hom(L,\Hom(X,E))$ which we know is exact. Thus $T=-\otimes X$ is right exact.

Comment: So, although $Q_2\to Q_1\to Q_0\to B\to 0$ is exact, one cannot deduce that it remains exact after tensoring with $A$. As an easy example to work through, consider the abelian group $B=\mathbb Z/2$, compute its projective resolution, and then tensor with $A=\mathbb Z/3$.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are trying to prove "by hand" that the zero map $A\to A$ induces the zero map $Tor_n^R(A,B)\to Tor_n^R(A,B)$. This is automatic since the $Tor$ functors are additive, but let's assume we want to check it explicitly. Your proof has a few issues.

First, it's not a mistake per se, but there is no need for $\bullet \otimes_R B$ to be right exact to induce a map of chain complexes: any additive functor works (the only thing needed is that the zero map is sent to the zero map).

---

The first real issue is that you are not working with the correct complex. In general if $$\dots\to P_2\to P_1\to P_0\to A\to 0$$ is a projective resolution of $A$ and $F$ is a right exact functor (in this case $F(X)=X\otimes_R B$), the derived functors are defined by the homology of the complex $$\dots \to F(P_2)\to F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to 0\quad (*)$$
and not $$\dots \to F(P_2)\to F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to F(A)\to 0.$$

Note that since the projective resolution is by definition exact, and $F$ is right exact, then $F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to F(A)\to 0$ is exact, but the complex $(*)$ is in general not exact at *any* point. In particular, $F(P_2)\to F(P_1)\to F(P_0)$ is *not* exact in general (it is exact exactly when $L_1F(A)=0$, so in this case $Tor_1^R(A,B)=0$).

Note that it is easy to recover $Tor_0^R(A,B)=A\otimes_R B$: by definition, $Tor_0^R(A,B)$ is the homology of $F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to 0$, so it is the cokernel of $F(P_1)\to F(P_0)$. But since $F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to F(A)\to 0$ is exact, the cokernel of $F(P_1)\to F(P_0)$ is naturally isomorphic to $F(A)$.

---

Another issue is your proof that $\tilde{\mu_0}\otimes B=0$. It is not necessarily the case: all you can deduce is that it has image in the kernel of $d_0\otimes B$. But the point is that even though it is not always the zero map, it always induces the zero map in the homology of the complex $(*)$.

The first way to see that is to use general properties: it is a basic fact of homological algebra that any choice of maps $\tilde{\mu_n}$, as long as they are compatible with the differentials, will induce the same map in the homology of $(*)$ (because two choices will always be chain homotopic). Since we can clearly choose $\tilde{\mu_n}=0$, any choice of $\tilde{\mu_n}$ must induce the zero map in homology.

If one wants to show everything by hand, we note that $\tilde{\mu_0}\otimes B$ has value in the kernel of $d_0\otimes B$; but by right exactess this is the image of $d_1\otimes B$, which is by definition the part of $P_0\otimes_R B$ which is sent to $0$ in the homology of the complex $(*)$ (so in $Tor_0^R(A,B)$).

Showing explicitly recursively that $\tilde{\mu_n}$ induces the zero map in homology for all $n$ is a little more tricky than you seemed to think in your answer, but it is not extremely difficult either. Just follow the proof that two choices of chain maps are homotopic, and adapt it to the case where one of the choices is the zero map.

Comment: Great, appreciate you pointing that out! Question, one part I am not sure, so right exact adds that that $P_2\otimes_R B\to P_1\otimes_R B\to P_0\otimes_R B\to A\otimes_R B\to 0$ is exact, we agree. So, when you take homology at $P_1\otimes_R B$ say, since this is exact, doesn't that mean that $Tor^R_1(A,B) =0$, also for $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Also, when you say Tor functors are additive, are you using the fact about additive functors that Tor maps the zero object to the zero object?

Comment: I am silly, I missed the fact that you were not working with the correct complex. I'll edit to address that.

Comment: About additive functors, here the important thing is that they send zero morphisms to zero morphisms (in general they preserve the additive structure of morphisms).

Comment: I see, but even in the (∗) complex, isn't it exact at (1) and if not, why? ( It is not exact at (0) because we removed () ) Why I think so is because the Im$(F(P_1))$ in $F(P_0)$ has not changed, correct? So the Ker of $ F(P_1) \to F(P_0)$ should be the same, hence equal to the Im$(F(P_2))$. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is not exact at $P_1$ because the functor $F$ is not exact but only right exact. It has nothing to do with removing $A$, this was never exact to begin with.

Comment: So let me resume, $... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to 0$ is not an exact sequence anyway, hence applying the right exact functor F to it, well we cannot say much about the resulting chain complex. It has nothing to do about the property of F being exact or right exact since the complex we started with is not exact.

Comment: I edited to add more details, hopefully it will make things clearer.

Comment: It does help a lot; my question is as you said $(_1)\to(_0)\to()\to0$ is exact, what makes the whole cochain complex $(*)$ not exact, like you said at any point? I can see why it would not be so at $F(P_0)$ but I am not sure why for n > 0.